# how to restore ssh connection after blocking port 22 in GCP compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I accidentally ran the command:

```
   sudo ufw deny 22
```

How can i fix this issue? using ssh is not possible.

Comment: What is a VPS server?

Comment: He refers to the Virtual Machine in GCP, ppl usually calls them VPS (Virtual private server)

Comment: I was mentally guessing that I could login through the serial port.  I created a VM and executed the OP command.  Sure enough, SSH now fails.  I then enable serial port login and got to a Linux login prompt ... not knowing what userid/password to use, I went back to the docs where they document how to create a userid/password ... using SSH in a logged on environment.  So a catch 22 ... using serial port login requires that you either know in advance you want serial or have a working SSH.

Comment: Why the down votes on this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following steps create a startup script that disables UFW so that you can recover from being locked out.

Note: The following example is for Debian based systems where `ufw` is installed in `/usr/sbin`. Adjust the path for your operating system version.

**Step 1:**

Login into the Google Cloud Console. Go to Compute Engine -> VM instances. Click on your instance. Click on the Edit button.

**Step 2:**

Scroll down to the section “Custom metadata”.

For Key enter:

```
startup-script
```

For Value enter:

```
/usr/sbin/ufw disable
```

Click the Save button

Note: An option is to enable SSH in the startup-script.

```
/usr/sbin/ufw allow ssh
```

**Step 3:**

Reboot your instance. During reboot, the startup-script will run disabling the UFW firewall. Log into your instance using SSH.

**Step 4:**

Repeat Step #2 except this time, delete the startup-script. Otherwise, the firewall will be disabled each time your instance boots.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) and add:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: Do not use `sudo` in Google Cloud Compute Engine startup scripts.